# How fix this error Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, sql

i have an problem with read an image of SQL 
the strucure the my table is the next

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nota] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Titulo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Imagen] [image] NOT NULL
)
```

an the fields than i have saved in the DB is the next

```
Id  Titulo          Imagen
1   Nombreimagen    0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D
```

and my code is the follow

```
try
{
   System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Nota WHERE ID = '1'", @"Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;User ID=User;Password=Pasword*");
   da.Fill(ds, "Imagen");

       byte[] imageBuffer = (byte[])ds.Tables["Imagen"].Rows[0]["Imagen"];
       System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBuffer);
       pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);         
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

and my error is the follow

**[System.ArgumentException] = {"Parameter is not valid."}**

in the next line

```
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: There are many answers on this site that handle the same error message. Did you look at these answers? Mainly the problem is caused by the fields bits in the database that are not a valid binary image data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error whenever GDI isn't able to make an image out of the bytes you feed it.

Let's look at what is in the image field:

```
0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D
```

If I put that through a HexString to Byte converter and then ASCII (it helps a bit if you know the [table](https://ascii.cl/)) decode the result, for example with this code:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(  StringToByteArray("53797374656D2E427974655B5D")).Dump();

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
  int NumberChars = hex.Length;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
  return bytes;
}
```

The result is:

> System.Byte[]

and that is not an image. It is the result of the ToString() method of the type that held your image when you tried to insert or update that row. You might want to make sure the SqlParameter for your image has its `DbType` property set to `DbType.Binary` when you try to save that image.

You can't fix the problem in the code you show here, fix the root cause, fix the content of the field `Imagen` in the row.

Comment: I have to wonder if the image value is actually encoded with ASCII, but great analysis that root cause is upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use data type  **varbinary(max)** instead of **image** data type, image data type is being deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

Comment: Why should this help?

Comment: Thanks for the solution that solved my problem Abrar Ahmad